# element.innerHTML can't call my javascript Function

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

I am so new to web development and I am encountering this problem. I tried googling this but the problems that I saw is not related to mine.

I have a jsp file that contains only this code:

```
<script>
displaymessage();
</script>
```

and in my js file: I have this.

```
$('ajax_content').innerHTML = resp.responseText;
```

where in the resp.responseText is equivalent to a string that represents the jsp file.

The function inside the jsp file is existing in the compiled HTML page but the function is not called.

The function's purpose is just to display a message.
Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Inserting a script via `innerHTML` does NOT run that script.

Instead, you should remove those `script` tags and just run the AJAX response through `eval`.